# Nuget Update - Specify MSBuild configuration to target

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

Is there a way to restrict the nuget update command to only update .proj references that match a particular condition?  (Or a clever workaround to get to the desired outcome)

**Scenario**

I have a project file that brings in different references depending on the     `${Configuration}` 
 type.   So, for example, if the `${configuration}` matches `ProjRef` it will set certain external references as `ProjectReferences`.  If the `${configuration}` matches the standard `Release` or `Debug` it will set certain external references as `References`.

This works great until nuget is added to the mix.  If I run a nuget update via command line it will modify the .proj file outside of the `${configuration}` conditionals and, therefore, override them if the added lines come *after* the `${configuration}` conditionals.

***Example***

Before Running Nuget Update

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">

  <Reference Include="X">
  <HintPath>path\1.2.2\X.dll</HintPath>

</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'ProjRef|AnyCPU' ">

  <ProjectReference Include="X.vbproj">
  <Name>X</Name>
  </ProjectReference>

</ItemGroup>
```

After Running Nuget Update:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">


</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'ProjRef|AnyCPU' ">

  <ProjectReference Include="X.vbproj">
  <Name>X</Name>
  </ProjectReference>

</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>

  <Reference Include="X">
  <HintPath>path\1.2.3\X.dll</HintPath>

</ItemGroup>
```

Notice that the lines added by nuget update will override the configuration specific lines resulting in no project reference -- even if built using `ProjRef` configuration.

Comment: Just quickly perusing the NuGet source code, it doesn't seem like there's a way to tell it to do what you need. I would file a bug on GitHub. Relevant source (for V2): https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/861741bd780225a542c73a1d0904dd33b33a7a3d/src/CommandLine/Common/MSBuildProjectSystem.cs

One way to work around this might be to tell NuGet to update a dummy .proj file, and then copy the new reference info out using a script or MSBuild task. Seems overtly complicated though, IMO.